# SelectNodes specific from a node

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to parse this field, but can't get it to work

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode link = 
    doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//ul[@class != 'menu']/li/ul/li/a[@href]");
```

I want to get only first `<ul>` node which does not have  `Class="menu"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't clear without seeing your HTML, but *"`<ul>` node which does not have `Class="menu"`"* can be translated into XPath as follow :

```
//ul[not(@class = 'menu')]
```

Then, by using `SelectSingleNode()` to execute the XPath it should return only the first element matched by the XPath parameter, as you wanted.

Comment: Thanks, its work for me. but now i want like something so can i do ?    SelectSingleNode"//ul[not (+Regex.IsMatch(class, @"^[a-z0-]menu)]/li/ul/li/a[@href]" )

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no regex support in XPath version 1 (the version that .NET implements)...

Comment: how can this possible ? have you any idea ?

Comment: You'll have to switch from XPath to LINQ, or mix the two

Comment: In a such way   ?                             DocumentNode.Descendants(tag).Where(d =>
                     d.Attributes.Contains(attribute)  && (Regex.IsMatch(d.Attributes[attribute].Value.ToLower(), @"^[a-z0-9-_]*menu[a-z0-9-_]*") ?

Comment: Yup, something like that. Only I'd rather use `d.GetAttributeValue("class","")` than `d.Attributes.Contains(attribute) && do-something-with d.Attributes[attribute].Value`

Comment: But here tag contains single elemet like "ul" not like "//ul[@class != 'menu']/li/ul/li/a[@href]" so how can get attribute value ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107731/discussion-between-logicbomb-and-har07).